# Importance of ? in ES query

Tags: elasticsearch

how the query URL is formed in elastic search and why we have a ? as below.Does this ? have any importance.Sample =” /kibana-int/dashboard/log-analytics-s?1431600189554

Answer (score 0):

`1431600189554` appears to be a timestamp (UNIX timestamp w/milliseconds), likely used to prevent caching of requests. It's not necessary for ElasticSearch (which will ignore it entirely), but it means the browser treats every request as a new URL and fetches new data.

Comment: the ? is for just an appending symbol or it signifies anything

Comment: @AishMahesh In a URL, the `?` denotes the beginning of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 0):

The "?" states that the rest of the URL will be parameters. As an example it's often used with the parameter "pretty" in ElasticSearch, when you query a mapping (like http://localhost:8080//_mapping?pretty). The "pretty" argument forces the return to be formatted in a way that is eye-friendly.

As a side note, the "&" character is used to separate arguments. For exemple http://localhost:8080//?lastname=foo&firstname=bar